# ADODB : Missing value in sum function

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

When I'm doing " sum(ev3.MT_BRUT) as Ecart " I lost all rows with ev3.MT_BRUT=.
My code is :

```
 RECSET2.Open " select dossier.NO_POLICE, ev1.D_EFFET, ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF, ev1.ID_PORTEFEUILLE, gr.LB_COURT_GR_EVT, pers1.S_PRENOM||' '||pers1.S_NOM as Collaborateur, proto.CD_PROTOCOLE, ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF,comm.L_COMMENT_DOSSIER," & _
" dossier.UI_CREATION, ev1.LP_STATUT_EVT, sum(ev3.MT_BRUT) as Ecart, ev1.MT_BRUT, tiers2.CD_TIERS as Tmandataire, pers3.S_RAISONSOC as Mandataire,tiers1.CD_TIERS as Tdepositaire, pers2.S_RAISONSOC as Depositaire, ev1.IS_EVENEMENT from DB_DOSSIER dossier left join DB_EVENEMENT ev1 " & _
" on dossier.IS_DOSSIER = ev1.IS_DOSSIER  left join DB_EVENEMENT ev2 on ev1.IS_EVENEMENT=ev2.IS_EVENEMENT_PERE  left join DR_LIEN_EVT drevl on ev2.IS_EVENEMENT=drevl.IS_EVENEMENT left join DB_EVENEMENT ev3 on drevl.IS_EVT_LIE=ev3.IS_EVENEMENT  left join DP_CLASSE_EVT cl on ev1.IS_CLASSE_EVT=cl.IS_CLASSE_EVT " & _
" left join DP_GROUPE_EVT  gr on cl.IS_GR_EVT=gr.IS_GR_EVT left join DB_COMMENT_DOSSIER comm on dossier.IS_DOSSIER=comm.IS_DOSSIER left join DR_COLLABORATEUR_PROTOCOLE collabproto on dossier.IS_PROTOCOLE=collabproto.IS_PROTOCOLE left join DB_COLLABORATEUR collab on collabproto.IS_COLLABORATEUR=collab.IS_COLLABORATEUR " & _
" left join DB_PERSONNE pers1 on collab.IS_PERSONNE=pers1.IS_PERSONNE left join DB_PROTOCOLE  proto on dossier.IS_PROTOCOLE=proto.IS_PROTOCOLE left join DB_PORTEFEUILLE  portef1 on ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF=portef1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF and  ev1.ID_PORTEFEUILLE=portef1.ID_PORTEFEUILLE left join DB_TIERS  tiers1 on tiers1.IS_TIERS=portef1.IS_TIERS_DEPOSITAIRE  " & _
" left join DB_PERSONNE  pers2 on tiers1.IS_PERSONNE=pers2.IS_PERSONNE left join DB_TIERS tiers2 on tiers2.IS_TIERS=portef1.IS_TIERS_GESTIONNAIRE left join DB_PERSONNE  pers3 on tiers2.IS_PERSONNE=pers3.IS_PERSONNE " & _
" where dossier.CD_DOSSIER in ('COROP','COROC') and dossier.LP_ETAT_DOSS not in ('CLOSE','ANNUL','A30') and ev1.D_EFFET>='" & Ma_date & "' and ev1.IS_EVENEMENT_PERE is null and drevl.LP_LIEN_EVT in ('COROP','COROC') " & _
" group by dossier.NO_POLICE, ev1.D_EFFET, ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF, ev1.ID_PORTEFEUILLE, gr.LB_COURT_GR_EVT, pers1.S_PRENOM, pers1.S_NOM, proto.CD_PROTOCOLE, ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF,comm.L_COMMENT_DOSSIER," & _
" dossier.UI_CREATION, ev1.LP_STATUT_EVT, ev1.MT_BRUT, tiers2.CD_TIERS, pers3.S_RAISONSOC,tiers1.CD_TIERS, pers2.S_RAISONSOC, ev1.IS_EVENEMENT ", cnn_Pegase, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic
```

I'm wondering if my export is working for the "Ecart" missing values :

```
 xlRow = Range("Chapeau").Row + 1 + xlRow
  If Not RECSET2.EOF Then
  Do While Not RECSET2.EOF
   
 ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_1").Column).Value = RECSET2("LB_COURT_GR_EVT").Value
 ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_2").Column).Value = RECSET2("Collaborateur").Value
 ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_3").Column).Value = RECSET2("CD_PROTOCOLE").Value
 ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_4").Column).Value = RECSET2("NO_POLICE").Value
```

---

```
  RECSET2.MoveNext
  xlRow = xlRow + 1
  Loop
  Else
  ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_1").Column).Value = ""
 ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_2").Column).Value = ""
 ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_3").Column).Value = ""
 ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_4").Column).Value = ""
 
*****************************************************************
  End If
  RECSET2.Close
  Call DECONNEXION_PEGASE
```

Thank your for help !

Comment: Do you mean you are missing rows where ev3.MT_BRUT=null ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes, but I don't kno why :(

Comment: What do you want null + null  or null + 1 to be ?

Comment: @CDP1802 For ev3.MT_BRUT with null I would like to desplay no values. I don't know how. I'm newer in VBA. When I run the same code in SAS with proc sql I have a '.' for  ev3.MT_BRUT=null. When I run the same code here I have no lines with  ev3.MT_BRUT=null.

Comment: But what if only some of the values being summated are null.You probably want `sum(NVL(ex3.MT_BRUT, 0))` see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: @CDP1802 Sorry, I didn't understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230859/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-marie).